# Fastest way to dynamically update the style of millions of DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, performance

I've built Conway's Game of Life in the browser just using the DOM. Nothing speical, it's been done before. My goal is to optimize it as best as I can. My actual Game of Life code works fine, and is fast enough for my liking. The bottleneck occurs in updating the screen state. With hundreds of thousands or millions of DOM elements on the screen, you can imagine that this can be quite slow (although faster than I first thought). My question is:

**Working with upwards of a million DOM elements on the screen at a time, what is the fastest way to iterate through a list of DOM elements and individually change their style?**

I'm using a class to keep track of styles, would it be better to dynamically change their `style` instead of `class`? I'm keeping all these elements in a multidimensional array, would it be better to iterate through another way (the loop itself is not a bottleneck, there are many such loops in my code that run fast enough for me)? I don't really know anything about "reflows" or how the browser renders things when elements change. Could these ideas be leveraged in a way that increases performance?

Here is my current code:

```
var updateUI = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        var row = grid[i];
        var rowUI = gridUI[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            rowUI[j].className = "b" + row[j];
        }
    }
}
```

with the class style being:

```
.b1 {
    background: #000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WE5jQ/

Comment: The DOM is not good at this sort of thing.  My snarky answer would be: don't, use canvas instead.

Comment: I understand this, and went into this project knowing that, anyway :) I expected at least one "use canvas" comment.

Comment: set up comparison tests in jsperf.com to assess

Comment: Nicely done @MattDiamant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide the grid into smaller regions and than update style only to elements in regions which are considered 'dirty' (contain at least one changed element compared to previous iteration). That should significantly reduce the amount of operations you need to do in each update UI call, especially when we're talking about millions of elements.

Comment: This is a good idea, and there is a version of this that I'm already planning on implementing. Keeping a "change list" of one's that need to be updated.

Answer (score 4):

Don't update the style of each one. Use the most general selector you can, and manipulate the actual style rules in the stylesheet. Let the browser do the rest of the work.

Comment: To be fair, the browser is doing the work regardless... but your point is valid.

Comment: Could you explain how to achieve this with the code that I've given? It doesn't seem like I can do that in my example. Each element needs to be styled independent of all others. There is no instance where I can operate on more than one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to optimize your loop performance, you could employ [Duff's Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) since you have a very large number of iterations. This is a technique of unrolling loop bodies so that each iteration actually does the job of many iterations. Jeff Greenberg is credited with the first published port of Duff’s Device to JavaScript. Here's the algorithm:

```
//credit: Jeff Greenberg
var i = items.length % 8;

while(i){
    process(items[i--]);
}

i = Math.floor(items.length / 8);

while(i){
    process(items[i--]);
    process(items[i--]);
    process(items[i--]);
    process(items[i--]);
    process(items[i--]);
    process(items[i--]);
    process(items[i--]);
    process(items[i--]);
}
```

At 500,000 iterations the execution time is up to 70% less than a regular loop.

Comment: I'd like to see a jsperf that measures the advantage. Maybe the JavaScript engines of 5 or 10 years ago benefitted from this, but I'm not sure that they do, these days.

Comment: This is a great way to optimize a loop, and I have thought of unwinding my loop a little bit, but as I mention about, the way that I'm looping through is not creating the bottleneck. The majority of the work is the way that I'm applying the style, which is what I'm trying to optimize. I'll definitely see how doing a bit of this affect performance, though.

Comment: Here's a JSPerf that compares a regular loop with several versions of Duff's Device. http://jsperf.com/duffs-device/28 At 500,000 iterations, the regular loop is 70% slower than any of the "Fast" Duff's Device test cases when I run it in Chrome 31.

Comment: Yes but almost nothing is done in the loop body. In real javascript code there is hardly ever a situation where loop body is so trivial that this optimization would make sense to do manually. In the OP's case there is insane amount of work being done in the loop body (String concatenation, DOM).

Comment: Really? A downvote? The OP asks "I'm keeping all these elements in a multidimensional array, would it be better to iterate through another way" This might not solve all of the performance bottlenecks but this is clearly a more-performant solution to that specific question. At 500,000 - 1,000,000+ iterations, you should always employ a technique like this regardless of the other work being done in the loop and I can't believe you would try to argue otherhwise.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is tagged as **jQuery**, you can use it to add/remove the class that you want. First, get an generic id/class that you use in your elements, then toggle the class that you want:

```
$('.generic-class').toggleClass('.another-class');
```

With this, you'll add `.another-class` to all existent elements that have the `.generic-class`.

And in your css:

```
.another-class { //other styles that you want to apply. }
```

Comment: Using jQuery is very slow. My code at first used `$('#g' + i + j)[0].className = "b" + row[j];` to get the cell, but I sped up performance greatly by caching the dom element and using plain javascript.

Comment: What do you mean by caching the dom element, etct?